# Ractive.js: Ractive.extend() global data

Tags: ractivejs

I try to add a button to a menu with Ractive.js and on click on this button sidebar should be opened.

js:

```
var ractive_setup = Ractive.extend({
  data: {
    data: {
      sidebar: false,
    }
  },
  onrender: function ( options ) {
    this.on({
      sidebar: function () {
        this.toggle('sidebar');
        console.log ( this.get('sidebar') );
      }
    });
  }
});

var ractive_sidebar_open = new ractive_setup({
  template: '#sidebar-open',
  el: '[data-ractive=sidebar-open]'
});

var ractive_sidebar = new ractive_setup({
  template: '#sidebar',
  el: '[data-ractive=sidebar]'
});
```

html:

```
<nav data-ractive="sidebar-open"></nav>
<script id="sidebar-open" type="text/ractive">
  <button class="open" on-click="sidebar">open sidebar</button>
</script>

<aside data-ractive="sidebar"></aside>
<script id="sidebar" type="text/ractive">
  {{ #if sidebar }}
  <button on-click="sidebar">close sidebar</button>
  <div class="sidebar-content">sidebar content</div>
  {{ /if sidebar }}
</script>
```

On *button.open* click, data changes only for one instance of `ractive_setup`—for the first one.

How to modify Ractive data globally, for both `ractive_setup` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your data-object outside, and pass it into both instances of your ractive_setup. With `magic mode` ([docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/magic-mode)) option on, both instances will then re-render when your data is modified.

Like this:

```
var ractive_setup = Ractive.extend({
  magic: true, //Magic mode to ensure re-render when data is modified
  onrender: function ( options ) {
    this.on({
      sidebar: function () {
        this.toggle('sidebar');
        console.log ( this.get('sidebar') );
      }
    });
  }
});

//declaring your data-object outisde, so you can pass it into both instances
var dataObj = {
    sidebar: false
};

var ractive_sidebar_open = new ractive_setup({
  template: '#sidebar-open',
  el: '[data-ractive=sidebar-open]',
  data: dataObj //passing in data to the first instance
});

var ractive_sidebar = new ractive_setup({
  template: '#sidebar',
  el: '[data-ractive=sidebar]',
  data: dataObj //passing in data to the second instance
});
```

I've created a working fiddle of your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/08huhfar/3/